# Carrierwave - upload multiple images at once to create model object for each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using Rails 4 with the carrierwave gem.  I have a model `user_item_images`.
A `user_item` has many `user_item_images`.

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "user_item_images", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "picture"
  end
```

I need a form that will accept multiple pictures and for each picture create its own model object.

**form**

```
<%= form_for :user_item_image, url: user_item_user_item_images_path(@user_item) do |f| %>
    <%= f.file_field :picture, multiple: true %>
    <%= f.submit %>
```

**controller**

```
  def create
    # raise 'foo'
    @user_item = UserItem.find_by_id(params[:user_item_id]).user_item_images.create(user_item_image_params)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def user_item_image_params
    params.require(:user_item_image).permit(:picture)
  end
```

I raised an error in the create action of the controller to check the value of `user_item_image_params` and I just get `{}`.

How can I submit multiple pictures at once and for each picture create a separate model object?

**UPDATE**

Following the answer below I changed my params to:

```
  def user_item_image_params
    params.require(:user_item_image).permit({picture: []})
  end
```

But when I submit nothing happens. I think I need to rewrite my create action.  Basically if I have

```
>>  user_item_image_params
=> {"picture"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f67d9b77d28 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160317-588761-mjk73n.JPG>, @original_filename="IMG_0313.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg",   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_item_image[picture][]\"; filename=\"IMG_0313.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f67d9b77d00 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160317-588761-edqw7.JPG>, @original_filename="IMG_0314.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_item_image[picture][]\"; filename=\"IMG_0314.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f67d9b77cd8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160317-588761-buatxk.JPG>, @original_filename="IMG_0315.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user_item_image[picture][]\"; filename=\"IMG_0315.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}
```

How can I make a model object out of each picture, in this case 3.

Answer (score 0):

The images need to be passed in as a hash and array.

```
def user_item_image_params
  params.require(:user_item_image).permit({picture: []})
end
```

Also, your model should use `mount_uploaders` instead of  `mount_uploader`.

```
class UserItemImages
  mount_uploaders   :picture
end
```

Comment: Great!  That fixed my problem of getting an empty hash, but now when I submit, it seems like nothing happens.  I think my create action is wrong.  How can I rewrite this so that it will create a model object for each picture uploaded?

Comment: Did you use mount_uploaders instead of mount_uploader?

Comment: I see on the carrierwave site where it says that but I think this is referring to storing all the images in a single column of a model.  I don't want to do that.  I want to make an individual model object for each picture according to my schema above.

Comment: If my `user_item_image_params` has a `:picture` key with a value all the info for all the pictures I need a way to pull that info out and build an object for each one.